# google - gmail account problem

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I have a account which uses a Google account, "ikh" For a variety of reasons, I had to login through smartphone, so I clicked "log in with Google". But, it logged me in with a Gmail account! I logged out of the google account and tried to log in again, but the same thing happened.

When I made the "ikh" account, I had a Google account, but I didn't have a Gmail account. When I try to log in through a smartphone, I have both a Google and Gmail account. Does the Gmail account "eat" the Google account? If so, why can't I log in to my "ikh" account?

As you know, I log in on Meta Stack Overflow as "user3020529", not "ikh". I cannot login as "ikh" except my desktop's Chrome browser, where I logged in as "ikh" first. It is possible to merge these accounts?

Comment: Same with me (using google GMAIL account) but without any smartphones. I can continue using my SO account from the tab where I am already logged in to SO but I cannot login in a new tab of the same browser or in different browser. Also I cannot post in MSO from the already existing account

Answer (score 2):

Please [contact us directly](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) to discuss this, we're going to need to ask you for information that you probably don't want to post publicly.

If you end up accidentally creating a new account during the login process, send us the following information:

- Email address(es) you used when signing up
- Links to your profile(s) if known

If unsure of the email, send us a list of possibilities. I'm [pretty sure I found you](https://stackoverflow.com/users/602114/ikh), and yes, I can merge, but you'll need to contact us privately to get that to happen because we'll need to verify some things.

Comment: oh.. I'm not http://stackoverflow.com/users/602114/ikh. I'm http://stackoverflow.com/users/2729109/ikh